# Highcharts tooltip on IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, tooltip, highcharts

If I user Highcharts "spline" graph it works fine on all browsers. Exceptionally on IE9 the tooltip has problem on display.

[image: see the problem with tooltip]

I think IE9 does not recognize SVG's "tspan" tag.

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please check this page:
http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=13457